# java : how to get the related value of stored index in arrayList

Tags: java, combobox, arraylist, jcombobox

I have stored the indexes of comboBox items in to array.  Now when I am retrieving it, I am getting the same indexes.

What I want that I want to show the related Value of that index.

Here is my code.

This is the function for add indexes into array.

```
public void addData() {

  // Retrive the text field values and combo box selected index and store them in variable
  int roomIndex = roomTypeCombo.getSelectedIndex();
  int mealIndex = mealCombo.getSelectedIndex();
  Int daysIndex = daysCombo.getSelectedIndex();

  //create the object of Customer class and pass the parameters
  Customer c = new Customer(roomIndex, mealIndex, daysIndex);
  myList.add(c); // add data into array list


} // end of function
```

This is the function for display stored values into the ArrayList

```
public void showAll() {
  String displayRecords = ""; // empty string

  // retrieve all stored records in array list and store in variable
  for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    displayRecords = displayRecords + myList.get(i) + "\n";
  }

  display.setText(displayRecords);
} // end of function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to use the "edit" link under your question to format it more readably. There's a preview shown under the edit area so you can always see what's going to be shown when you post your question, as well as lots of handy formatting information to the right of the text area ("How to Format") and in links above it (the **[?]** button kicks things off).

Comment: How does the toString() method looks like in your Customer Class?

Comment: Also, for best practice, please don't use `String displayRecords`, and `displayRecords += xxx`, cuz string is an immutable object, should use StringBuffer

Comment: public String toString()
   {
    return RoomTypeItem+" "+MealTypeItem+" "+DaysIndex; this is my toString class inside customer class.

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If showing the value of combobox is your requirement, then instead of

```
int roomIndex = roomTypeCombo.getSelectedIndex();
int mealIndex = mealCombo.getSelectedIndex();
Int daysIndex = daysCombo.getSelectedIndex();
```

Why don't you use following code:

```
String room = (String) roomTypeCombo.getSelectedItem();
String meal = (String) mealCombo.getSelectedItem();
String days = (String) daysCombo.getSelectedItem();
```

And create a constructor of `Customer` so that following would be true:

```
Customer c = new Customer(room, meal, days);
```

Comment: What would that buy you? Creating a new Customer Object with 3 string instead of 3 int. You are still dealing with a customer object as he concat onto a string.

Comment: Please notice I have replaced `getSelectedIndex()` with `getSelectedItem()`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your customer object contains three members named roomIndex, mealIndex and daysIndex since you do this: `Customer c = new Customer(roomIndex, mealIndex, daysIndex);`

The showAll method that you posted will not print out the values as you are expecting. This is because each element in myList is a object of customer, and not a string. A customer object contains different strings tho (roomindex, mealindex, daysindex) so if you want to print them you will need getters in your customer class. Once you have that you can print the content of a customer class like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println( myList.get(i).getRoomIndex() + " " + myList.get(i).getMealIndex() + " " + myList.get(i).getDaysIndex()+"\n");
  }
```

The methods getRoomIndex etc, should be a method inside Customer that returns a string, like this:

```
public String getRoomIndex(){
   return roomIndex;
}
```

EDIT:
I missed that you only took the index from the comboBox and my solution expects the value rather then the index. You can fetch the item right away like Garbage stated in his post. The method getSelectedItem returns a object of type Object, so that's why he's casting it to a string. This can be dangerous tho if the item you fetch is not a string so it might not be considered a waterproof solution but might work in your example

Comment: If inside his Customer Class, if he has a toString method, displayRecords + myList.get(i), automatically cast Customer to a string, therefore, if his toString method is to return the 3 members, than that doesn't matter, u don't need getRoomIndex ....

Comment: Indeed that is true (if the method is written correctly). Altho i didn't not expect him to have a toString method since he did not post one. But +1 for noticing and clearing that out :)

Comment: sorry, ya i do have the toString() method inside customer class but i havn't mention here. but ya i solve my problem by storing directly index items. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you **only** hold the indexes of the items **not** the values of the items you may call and display the values from your combobox as the following:

```
public void showAll() {
  String displayRecords = ""; // empty string
  int roomIndex;
  int mealIndex;
  int daysIndex; 

  // retrieve all stored records in array list and store in variable
  for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    roomIndex = ((Customer)(myList.get(i)).roomIndex;
    mealIndex = ((Customer)(myList.get(i)).mealIndex;
    daysIndex = ((Customer)(myList.get(i)).daysIndex;
    displayRecords = displayRecords + roomTypeCombo.getItemAt(roomIndex) + " " + 
      roomTypeCombo.getItemAt(mealIndex) + " " + roomTypeCombo.getItemAt(daysIndex)
     + "\n";
  }

  display.setText(displayRecords);
} // end of function
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you print out roomIndex, mealIndex, daysIndex before you create the Customer Object. Just to see you are getting the values correctly before you create the object.